# How to programatically add constraints on uinavigationbar subview

Tags: ios, autolayout, uinavigationbar, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I'm adding a subview to navigationbar , problem is that im unable to add constraints to it .Im getting crash like this

> terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with items ; value: 0.000000> and > because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

The code used is below

```
//create a slider and add it to the view
        let slider = UISlider()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(slider)

        //pin the slider 20 points from the left edge of the the superview
        //from the left edge of the slider to the left edge of the superview
        //superview X coord is at 0 therefore 0 + 20 = 20 position
        let horizonalContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: slider, attribute:
            .LeadingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view,
            attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 20)

        //pin the slider 20 points from the right edge of the super view
        //negative because we want to pin -20 points from the end of the superview.
        //ex. if with of super view is 300, 300-20 = 280 position
        let horizonal2Contraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: slider, attribute:
            .TrailingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view,
            attribute: .TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -20)

        //pin 100 points from the top of the super
        let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: slider, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)

        //when using autolayout we an a view, MUST ALWAYS SET setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints
        //to false.
        slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        slider.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        //IOS 8
        //activate the constrains.
        //we pass an array of all the contraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([horizonalContraints, horizonal2Contraints,pinTop])
```

The above code works fine if i use the line             `view.addSubview(slider)`
instead of

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(slider)
```

But the idea is to add constraints on a subview on navigation bar .
Any thoughts are welcome

Answer (score 2):

As the exception already stated, the navigationBar is not a subview of 'view'. It belongs to the navigationcontroller.
What you could do is to use the navbar's superview:

```
let slider = UISlider()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(slider)
let targetView = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.superview

let horizonalContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: slider, attribute:
    .LeadingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: targetView,
    attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0,
    constant: 20)

let horizonal2Contraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: slider, attribute:
    .TrailingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: targetView,
    attribute: .TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -20)


let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: slider, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal,
    toItem: targetView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)


slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
slider.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([horizonalContraints, horizonal2Contraints,pinTop])
```

That removes the exception and might look like it does what you want, but **it is definitely not a good solution**. If you want the slider inside the navbar, add it to the navigationitem instead. If you want it bellow the navbar, add it to your View and set a constraint to the top layout guide.